# Disable web crawling for Nextjs app from robots.txt for particular sub-domain only

Tags: web-crawler, seo, vercel, robots.txt, google-crawlers

I have my website deployed on vercel, The site is a Next js application directly (not using nginx or any other web serving servers) deployed on vercel. There are two domains assigned to the same website. One is the subdomain (testers.example.com), other is the main site ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)). Both of these use the same codebase (it is required so), therefore the robots.txt is same for both the domains. But I don’t want to enable crawling for testers.example.com keeping it active on [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) . How can I perform this?

I tried:
`Disallow: tester.example.com`
But this didn't worked out as relative address is used in Allow and Disallow attribute